# Wi-Fi drivers cause a stream of error messages on Void Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, drivers, void-linux

I installed a Void Linux partition on my Macbook Air and needed the Broadcom Wi-Fi drivers to enable Wi-Fi. I used the script [found here](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/) to install them, but after installation when I boot into the partition and the drivers activate I get many error messages which prevent me from using the partition:

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0f1u1: link ready
bce-vhci: Unhandled system event: 50 s=0 p1=0 p2=0
bce-vhci: Not implemented: wait for pending output requests
bce-vhci: Possible desync, cmd cancel timed out
```

The last two errors continue being printed repeatedly.

How could I fix this?